# A little question about $F_g = F_c$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

It is already some time ago that I was fluent in classical mechanics.
I do not understand a certain detail in the formula $F_{grav.}=F_{centr.}$.
Probably I overlook something simple.

Suppose mass $m$ circles around mass $M$ at distance $d$ with constant speed $v = 2\pi d/T$.
Then $$GmM/d^2 = mv^2/d.$$

Now suppose I consider this circular movement with mass $m$ in the centre. Distance, speed and period are the same, so:
$$GmM/d^2 = Mv^2/d.$$

What is my error?

Both $m$ and $M$ rotate uniformly in a circle around the center of mass. This is the preferred point of view that is easy to understand.
Still one can assume a reference frame on $m$ in rest for an observer on $m$ in rest. $M$ definetely moves with the same speed, period and distance. Ergo sum the centripetal force in this reference frame can no longer be formulated as $Mv^2/d$.
But how does the observer on $m$ get to know that?
Could anybody elaborate on whether and how this particular situation may be calculated?
As a matter of fact it seems that in this reference frame besides gravity there must appear to be a "fictious" repelling force that equals $(m-M)v^2/d$.

Comment: Why do you expect the orbit of the larger mass around the smaller (assuming the smaller mass is fixed in place somehow) to have the same radius and velocity?

Comment: Let's turn it around: are you saying this is impossible?

Comment: Both objects orbit around their common center of mass, and the point that they orbit around cannot be arbitrarily changed.

Comment: @DavidWhite when you are in rest on $m$ that is a valid point of view and $M$ turns in a perfect circle.

Comment: @Gerard, the centripetal force formula applies only to the distance from the center of an object to the center of mass that it is orbiting around in a circular path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation of the answer of Claudio Saspinksi:

Choosing M as the inertial frame of reference gives
$$\frac{GMm}{r^2} = m\omega^2 r \cdot \frac{M}{M+m}= m\omega^2 r 
\cdot (1 - \frac{m}{M+m})$$ where $ - \frac{m^2\omega^2 r}{M+m}$ is a (pseudo) centrifugal force experienced by m.
The observer on M cannot observe it.

Choosing m as the inertial frame of reference gives
$$\frac{GMm}{r^2} = M\omega^2 r \cdot \frac{m}{M+m} = M\omega^2 r \cdot (1 - \frac{M}{M+m})$$ where $ - \frac{M^2\omega^2 r}{M+m}$ is a (pseudo) centrifugal force experienced by M.
The observer on m cannot observe it.

The lesson I learn is that by not choosing the center of mass as the frame of reference, you will have to take (pseudo) centrifugal forces into account.
I don't think many people are aware of this...

Also this shows that you don't need a rotating frame of reference for pseudo forces to emerge. Also you don't need a non-inertial frame of reference. In both cases we have a non-rotating inertial frame of reference.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong - neither of those reference frames are inertial from the point of view of Newtonian mechanics.  The hallmark of a non-inertial frame is the presence of pseudo forces; inertial frames are precisely those in which no such "forces" arise.  This is the statement of Newton's first law.

Comment: You are probably correct. Stil. m cannot observe any pseudo force acting on M and an observer on M is also in rest. These particular pseudo forces are therefore unobservable, nobody can tell whether they "arise", they arise theoretically.

Comment: Maybe we can set the center of mass equal to the center of a spinning carousel and m and M two persons on the carousel diametrically opposite at different distances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The fact that your observers are in non-inertial frames is made clear by thinking about the situation from the perspective of an external observer, which implies that Newton's 2nd law is not going to hold unless an extra term is added.  This term can be derived empirically by simply defining $\mathbf F_{pseudo}= M\mathbf a - \mathbf F_{grav}$, or by starting in an inertial frame and changing coordinates, in which case the extra term arises due to the rate of change of your basis vectors when computing $\frac{d\mathbf v}{dt}$, both methods yielding the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Neither formula is exact (assuming that Newtonian gravity is the only force affecting the two masses): a reference frame in which $m$ moves circularly while $M$ is stationary is not inertial, since in an inertial frame $M$ will move by the force exerted by $m$.
The same is true for the reverse.

The first formula holds in the approximation that $M \gg m$: then the force exerted by $m$ causes a negligible acceleration of the mass $M$, which we can then approximate as stationary.
We are considering $m$ to be a so-called "test mass".

The reverse, on the other hand, would be a really bad approximation, since the force on $m$ is definitely not negligible - it is what causes the motion, after all!

Comment: It's not the most physically realistic scenario, but one could imagine that the mass being orbited is fixed in place somehow, so this frame could in principle be inertial.  Gravity is the only force acting on the *orbiting* mass, but the same need not be true of the other one.

Comment: Could you eleborate on how to calculate the situation with the small mass in the centre? Suppose you are on the small mass $m$ and you are certain that M goes around in a circle? In the framework of classical mechanics these formules are not approximations why do you mention that?

Comment: @Gerard if you want to work in a reference frame that is attached to the small mass, then   the expression $F=ma$ gets more complicated: as described, for example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force#Orbiting_coordinate_systems) there will appear a "fictitious force" (the name is unfortunate, it is quite real) on the large mass, causing it to "orbit" the small mass in a circle.

Comment: @J.Murray you're right, I have edited the answer to make that assumption explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If mass $M$ is fixed in place and mass $m$ (which is only under the influence of Newtonian gravity) is in a circular orbit of radius $R$ and speed $v$, then
$$G\frac{Mm}{R^2} = \frac{mv^2}{R}$$
$$\implies v^2 R = GM$$
This is a constraint between $v$ and $R$.  In other words, circular gravitationally-bound orbits around $M$ cannot have arbitrarily chosen speed and radius; given some speed, there is only one radius at which such an orbit is possible, and vice-versa.

If instead we fix $m$ in place, then circular orbits around $m$ obey a similar constraint, but now we have that $v^2 R = Gm$.  If $m\neq M$, then circular orbits of radius $R$ around $M$ will have a different speed than circular orbits of radius $R$ around $m$.

---

Jacopo also makes a good point in his answer.  If you assume that *both* masses are only under the influence of Newtonian gravity, then neither one orbits the other; instead, they both orbit their mutual center of mass.  If one mass is much larger than the other, then the larger mass will be approximately stationary and we might say that the smaller mass is approximately in orbit around it, but that's not *exactly* true.

Comment: I of course assumed we are in rest on the smaller mass $m$ and we see the perfect circle of $M$, so you cannot say that "neither one orbits the other" bc. that is a direct observation. Of course $m$ and $M$ turn around the center of mass too and these formulas are correct. Note that the difference of these circles are the circle with radius $d$. It seems that for the observation $M$ around small $m$ one cannot use $F=ma$ in such a simple way. I will have to read the Wiki page that Jacopo Tissino mentions.

Comment: @Gerard That wasn't at all obvious from your question.  I can and *do* say that, because it is true in any inertial frame of reference.  Saying that there exists a non-inertial frame in which one mass orbits the other is true, but it is equally true to say that there is a frame in which the sun orbits the Earth, and a frame in which the Milky Way galaxy orbits my apartment.

Comment: @J .Murray: Sorry for not being clear enough. The observer on $m$ must believe he/she is in an inertial frame, he/she is in rest, isn't it? How does he/she discover that there are "fictious" (but just as real) forces in the circular orbit of $M$ around $m$?

Comment: @Gerard That misconception could be cleared up by observational evidence to the contrary (see [this nice blog post](https://beforenewton.blog/daily-readings/galileo-and-heliocentrism/) which describes the evidence Galileo accumulated to discover that the Earth is not an inertial frame) or in principle by applying Newton's Laws and discovering that they don't hold.  As you noted in your very question, naive application of Newton's laws in a non-inertial frame yields contradictions which require (a) the addition of pseudo-forces or (b) moving to a truly inertial frame to resolve.

Comment: You must be right. I would never have thought of this myself. B.t.w. do you agree that the centrifugal pseudo-force must be $(m-M)v^2/d$? This looks like there must exist a not so difficult reason/derivation for it?

Answer (score 2):

From a purely kinematic perspective, M is orbiting m and m is orbiting M with the same angular speed.

The Newtonian gravity supposes a force between the masses, that we can imagine as a tension in a giant massless rod: $$T = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

The system is rotating as a rigid body around its COM. The centripetal force is the tension in the rod:
$T = m\omega^2 r_m = M\omega^2 r_M$

As $\omega$ is the same:
$$m r_m = M r_M \implies m r_m = M (r-r_m) \implies r_m = \frac{Mr}{M+m}$$

$$\frac{GMm}{r^2} = m\omega^2 r_m = M\omega^2 r_M \implies \omega = \sqrt{\frac{G(M+m)}{r^3}}$$

As $\omega$, $r$ and $G$ can be determined, we can say that the masses are the output of the theory.